# How does a CPU choose a path?

Tags: communication, cpu, data

This is the most baffling question of all other concepts. I ask my teacher

"How does the computer choose a path?"

"They program it"

"How do they program it?"

"..."

I have a basic understanding of how a transistor works, how the CPU handles things, and the latter, but how does the CPU physically choose a path!? I want to learn the college level stuff, but google is not helping!!! All I get are these novice translations! Please help because I'm crying over not knowing the answer. Literally.

**EDIT:**  I need a thorough answer explaining what is going on in the hardware please.

Comment: It's obvious when there are humans to physically choose a path, but how is this done through hardware exactly? I can choose to flip one of three switches on a wall, and they go to a *set* path. if there are multiple connections coming from the cpu to the bus with the RAM and gosh knows what other connections, what is physically telling the electrons to only go to one path instead of all the connections on the bus? More or less it's obvious with a hard drive, but not SSD.

Comment: What do you mean by "choose a path"?

Comment: It sounds like the missing piece might be a knowledge of logic circuits. What ends up on a bus is the result of the combination of inputs on a logic gate at a particular time, so the combination of logic gates could be considered as choosing the path data takes.

Comment: Wait is it really just logic gates in the CPU? So does that mean the bus is hard-wired to a specific location on the motherboard? And yes, I know all about logic circuits. I build them all the time.

Comment: Well that would explain how data goes left rather than right and vice versa, but how do you flip the switches? another call from the cpu? and how is that call made? and so on. I need a graphical example of how this works. Can someone show me a circuit diagram from the cpu to the bus and to other parts of the board, perhaps labeled with the Logic gates. I would assume most of the gates are XORs.

Comment: I think the Programmer needs explanation on Datapath. In brief, the datapath is composed of a combination of registers and multiplexers, which are linked to ALU. A definite combination when applied to the multiplexers results in a particular operation. (If that is indeed what you are looking for, let me know. I'll put in more details ).

Comment: You should edit some of your comment clarifications into the question so that people only have to read one place.

Comment: @Plutoniumsmuggler I think that is what I've been looking for! I know the ALU can do many logical operations, question is, everything is going to the same bus, so there must be other logic gates along the way to direct if further? But then the logic gate requires other input, so where does that one come from? Also if logic gates are the answer, then WHY ARE COMPUTERS SO ENERGY INEFFICIENT?

Comment: Computers are extremely efficient, they're just asked to do a lot. You can get several billion transistors and their battery in the palm of your hand.

Comment: I don't know of any explanation which goes directly from logic gates to CPU, or computer. There are too many gates involved. Even an old 4 bit CPU (e.g. [4004](http://www.cedmagic.com/history/intel-4004.html), which was as simple as it ever got, used 2000 transistors, and hence many hundreds of logic gates. So a diagram would be unmanageable. Instead logic gates are collected into higher level functions, like a flip flop then many make a register, or full-adder then many make part of an ALU.

Comment: Huh? What does *"choose a path"* mean? Are you asking how a person decides what the overall operation of a processor to perform is, or how that gets translated to a computer language, or how that gets translated to machine instructions, or how the machine knows what the instruction tell it to do, or how the machine knows which instruction to execute next, or something else? Your question is very ambiguous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll make a brief attempt to explain the Datapath implementation, since it is a large topic.

[image]

CONTROL WORD : Control Word is basically the input code ( You can say, The master code) which controls what operation the computer will perform. A General control word will consist of an opcode, specifying a particular operation, like add or shift, followed by a few parameters like location of operands or the operand itself etc. In this figure, the control word wont be directly visible, so I have added another figure. Be careful, the second figure is not directly related to the first one.

[image]

Here a simple control word is shown.

---> DA stands for Destination and specifies the location where the result of computation will be stored.

---> AA and BA specify the location of operands A and B.

---> MB, MD are the Mux B and Mux D enable input (More on that later).

---> FS is the function select, and specifies what function the unit will perform.

Now back to figure 1.

---> A select and B select inputs are applied to Mux A and Mux B, which select the data inputs from the registers R0 through R3.

---> The input B is then passed to Mux b, to decide whether it is needed or not, because some operations only require a single operand, like shift and increment.

---> The A input and the output of Mux B ( which consists of either input B or a constant, as seen in the figure) is then applied to ALU. Note that B input is also applied to the shifter.

---> The opcode or Function select determines what operation will it be. At this point, the output of both the shifter and ALU is applied to Mux F, which selects whether it the output of ALU or Shifter which is needed. The Mux F select maybe a part of opcode.

---> Finally, the result passes through Mux D, and then it is applied to each of the registers for storage purposes. Which register to store in is decided by the And gates which enable Loading operation, with the address of the registers applied via decoder.

I hope this explains it.

Comment: Can someone please up vote him for me? @plutoniumsmuggler thanks. Now I should ask how to access memory via C so I can continue making my operating system's file system.

Comment: @LinkTheProgrammer . Sorry about that. That a computer Science question. Better check on Stack overflow.

Comment: @Link Voting on answers is based on whether users deem it *useful* and *correct*. You can make a comment that a given answer was helpful and encourage others to vote on it, but realize that nobody is obligated to do so.

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by saying "choose a path"?

All a modern CPU is, is a fancy hardware interpreter. It starts like this:

You issue a command in a high level language like:

```
i = 5 + 6;
```

This gets translated to machine instructions (and pseudo instructions), commonly known as assembly, by the compiler:

```
mov ebx, 5
mov eax, 6
add eax, ebx
```

This gets translated to bytes, the direct equivalent of assembly that the cpu can understand, by another class of translators known as assemblers:

```
01010111 00110101 00000101
01010111 00110111 00000110
01111111 00110101 00110111
```

The Control Unit of the CPU, then reads the first byte of the instruction, rougly known as `opcode`. Depending on the opcode, the control unit asserts control signals to different parts of the cpu, such as enabling one register to send its contents to the ALU, or reading from the instruction store to a register, etc, depending on the instruction.

For instance, in the above example, `01010111` or what you know as `mov` instruction, might
signal passthrough of the immediate value 5 through the ALU to the register known as `00110101` or `eax`.

The internals of the interpreter, or the control store, or however it's called in different implementations, differ from implementation to implementation. For example, in a microcode
storing implementation, there might be a small memory mapping opcodes to corresponding signals, likewise:

```
01010111 -> enable_ALU_passthrough, reg, immediate_val
01111111 -> enable_ALU_add, reg, reg
```

That's a rough example of how a cpu might work. Values are approximate and almost certainly are not correct. If you want to dig through, I recommend the excellent [Structured Computer Organization by Tanenbaum](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0132916525) which walks you through building a simple CPU interpreting java bytecode in the first few chapters.

Comment: What NlightNFotis said was true. I should add that it would be helpful to read about hardware multiplexers/demultiplexers. And think that depending on each opcode, there is a different demultiplexing path.

Answer (score 2):

Ken Shirrif has a number of blog entries which take apart microprocessors of the 80s in loving detail:

http://www.righto.com/2013/09/the-z-80-has-4-bit-alu-heres-how-it.html
http://www.righto.com/2013/01/a-small-part-of-6502-chip-explained.html
http://www.righto.com/2014/09/why-z-80s-data-pins-are-scrambled.html
(etc).

The 6502 is a good subject for this as it's one of the last microprocessors to be designed by a single engineer, by hand, on paper (well, acetate sheet with "Rubylith" tape).

There's also "NAND to Tetris": http://www.nand2tetris.org/

Answer (score 0):

If you have a single input signal which the MCU/CPU wants to route to differernt locations, as shown in "DEMUX" below, then the MCU forcing A/Bbar high will result in IN going to A, and by forcing A/Bbar low, IN will be sent to B.

In the MUX, if A/Bbar is forced high, A will be sent to C, and if A/Bbar is forced low, B will be sent to C.

So, you can see that in one case a signal can be sent to many locations sequentially, and, in the other, many signals can be sent, sequentially, to a single location.

[image]